# Kubernetes cluster with certificate authority

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, certificate-authority, google-kubernetes-engine

Certificate error after upgrade of kubernetes
Error is SSL certificate problem:unable to get local issuer certificate

After doing multiple modifications Now I'm getting above error.

Comment: Refer to this [gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/issues/327) helpful to resolve your issue

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because the curl verifies and makes a secure connection request using self-signed certificate. When it does not find the valid certificate, it throws an error.

1)Download and extract  https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem and  follow the instructions at .https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

2)Copy the entire page and save it as a “cacert.pem”
Add the '--cacert /path/to/cacert.pem' option to the curl command to tell curl where the local Certificate Authority file is.
If you add the CA certificate from certificate-authority-data field to the curl command, it will work.

3)Add the following line to a ".curlrc" file: `cacert = /path/to/cacert.pem.` For information about where curl looks for this file, see "man curl" in the "-K, --config file>" section.

4)On the other hand if utilizing php add the accompanying line to php.ini: ( You could add this to.user.ini in public_html if you don't have access to php.ini because this is shared hosting. Open your php.ini file and insert or update the following line).

```
curl.cainfo = “[pathtofile]cacert.pem”
```

Refer to this [doc](https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html) for more details on SSL certificate verification.